# Add Pagination by Text box

Tags: pagination

I would like to use pagination by text box where client can type the number of product page and click go/submit button.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php  $totalpage=$collection->getLastPageNumber(); //get total number of pages
$currentUrl = Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl();

 ?>
<input type="text" name="pager" id="pager"> <input type="button" value="go" onClick="gopage()">

<script>
function gopage()
{
  vale=$('pager').getValue();
  if(vale >=<?php echo totalpage; ?>) {
  window.location='<?php echo currentUrl ?>?page'+vale;
   }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

you must insert the code below in

```
\app\design\frontend\YOURTEMPLATE\default\template\page\html\pager.phtml
```

or

```
\app\design\frontend\YOURTEMPLATE\default\template\catalog\product\list\toolbar.phtml
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php  $totalpage=$_productCollection->getLastPageNumber(); //get total number of pages
        echo "Total Page is " . $totalpage;
        $currentUrl = Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl();
        //echo $currentUrl;
         ?>
            | Enter Page Number: <input type="text" name="pager" id="pager"> <input type="button" value="Go To Page" onClick="gopage()">

        <script>
        function gopage()
        {
            var x = '<?php echo $currentUrl; ?>';
            //alert(x);
            var url = x.split('?')[0];
            //alert(url);

         vale=document.getElementById("pager").value;
          //alert(vale);

          if(isNaN(vale)==true || Number(vale) >'<?php echo $totalpage; ?>') {
                alert('Your maximun page number is ' + '<?php echo $totalpage; ?>');

           }
           else{
                window.location=url+'?p='+vale;     
           }    
        }
        </script>
```

Comment: Please add some explanation: what does the code do, where do you add it? Code-only answers are not very helpful.